# How to write the javascript test code on whether a smart contract function is successfully executed or not?

Tags: solidity, javascript, smart-contract-wallets, truffle-test, mocha

I wrote a lottery smart contract and gonna to test an "enter" functionality of the smart contract.
[image]

The below code is javascript test code for the "enter" function of the smart contract.

[image]

When I call "enter" function with less than 0.01 ether, how can I continue the test code? (//??? part below contract.enter(...) line)
In the enter function of lottery smart contract, the execution will be restricted if the msg.value is less than 0.01 ether. How can I detect it in the test code?

Comment: You can't the function has a require that will cause a revert and skip to the catch block, you either use the correct amount or change the test.

Comment: Could you let me know more exactly about what you said?

Comment: if the answer helped you please upvote and accept

Answer (score 0):

mercifully, you don't need the try catch blocks if you're expecting it to throw an error

chai test syntax

```
await expect(myContract.callFunc()).to.be.revertedWith("my expected error message")
```

or if you don't want to check the message

```
await expect(myContract.callFunc()).to.be.reverted
```

or

```
await expect(myContract.callFunc()).to.throw
```

and for test that return a value you might use something like

```
    // expecting number 2
    expect(await myContract.getNumber()).to.equal(2)
```